# Couldn't able to get data back from actionCreator

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Lately i have been working around in redux and was trying to get my hands on, I tried async calling by redux-thunk.
I am showing the relevent files.
**Posts.js**
This file is calling getPosts() in componentdidmount which in return tries to get data from actionCreator.

```
 import React,{Component} from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios'
import CardPost from '../Post/Post'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import classes from './Posts.module.css'
import {Link,Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {getPost} from '../../Store/action/posts'
class Posts extends Component{


    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getPosts()
    }

    render(){
        let post =<p>Loading data...</p>
       if(this.props.bulkPost.length>0){
           console.log("rendering again")
            post =  this.props.bulkPost.map((item)=>{
            return(

    <Col as={Link} to={"/posts/"+item.id} className={classes.topMargin} key={item.id} sm={4}> 
        <CardPost/>
    </Col>

            )

           })
       }
        return(
            <>
            <div>
                 <Container>
                        <Row> 
                            {post}
                        </Row>
               </Container>
            </div>

        </>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state=>{
    return{ 
        bulkPost: state.pos.posts,
        // oneLineData: state.full.fetchedText
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return{

        // onDeleteResult: (id)=>dispatch(actionCreator.deleteResult(id)),
        getPosts:()=>dispatch(getPost())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Posts)
```

This is my actionCreator 
**posts.js**
It utilizes redux thunk middleware and tries to get data Async, on checking by console.log(res), data is being fetched in the file.

```
    import {POSTS} from '../action/actionType'
import Axios from 'axios'

export const savePost = (res)=>{
    return{
        posts: res,
        type:POSTS

    }
}

export const getPost = ()=>{
    return (dispatch)=>{
        Axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/").then((response)=>{    
        dispatch(savePost(response.data));
        })
    }
}
```

And now the third file where the data should be ideally dispatched, and should be returned to us

```
    import * as actionType from '../action/actionType'
const intitalState = {
    posts:[]
}

const reducer = (state=intitalState, action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case actionType.POSTS:
                console.log(state)
                const post  = state.posts.slice(0,4);
                const updatedPost = post.map((post)=>{
                    return{
                    ...post
                    }
                })
                    return{
                        ...state,
                        posts:updatedPost
                    }
    }
    return state
}

export default reducer
```

Here the state posts is not being populated by dispatch method in the first file.
Can someone please help, what i am doing wrong over here ?
Edit:
this is the full working project online
https://codesandbox.io/s/4xwlwl70v0

Comment: What I am not seeing here is your use of middleware such as `redux-thunk` since you are now making asynchronous action creators, but it looks like you already have your answer.

Comment: Yes i have used it, in actionCreator, since, the redux is always sync the, thunk make it async. Do correct me if i am wrong, i am really a beginner in redux /\

Comment: That's correct, redux cannot handle asynchronous JavaScript out of the box and that is the purpose of middlewares such as Redux Thunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your actioncreator you can dispatch the action directly:

```
import Axios from 'axios'
import {POSTS} from '../action/actionType'

export const getPost = ()=>{
    return (dispatch)=>{
        Axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/").then((response)=>{    
            dispatch({
                type: POSTS,
                posts: response.data
            });
        })
    }
}
```

In your reducer, you're mapping the results from the API-call. I don't see the purpose of mapping the result? The posts from the action creator is available on action.posts.

```
import * as actionType from '../action/actionType'
const initalState = {
    posts: []
}

const reducer = (state = initalState, action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case actionType.POSTS:
            const posts = action.posts.slice(0,4);
            return{
                ...state,
                posts: posts
            }
    }
    return state
}

export default reducer;
```

Without seeing your combinedRecduers, is this a typo?

```
const mapStateToProps = state=>{
    return{ 
        bulkPost: state.pos.posts, // maybe state.post.posts ?
        // oneLineData: state.full.fetchedText
    }
}
```

Comment: No, i have combined them, i have a link in the post which link to online dev env, you can see there i have combined both

Comment: I mapped the result because the redux dosent support async calls, so the result have to be mapped, see my concept might be bit broken but that what i think it should be

Comment: You don't have to map the result. By default, Redux action creators don’t support asynchronous actions like fetching data thats why you're using thunk. I've applied my changes to your code and it works, https://codesandbox.io/s/r772pov6zp.

Comment: In your reducer, const post  = state.posts.slice(0,4); state.posts is an empty array. Thats why you never get any posts back to the component

Comment: Wow, you are a life saver, let me see in the code what i did wrong

Comment: This was such a face palm, it was such a bad question, i was really confused in the redux yesterday, this might be the result of it. Thanks for the help. :-D